# dark - light mode button

Tags: javascript, button, darkmode, lightmode

I want to change the body's bg to white, when it is set to "sun" (light mode) and change back to moon (also change the background to black with it)

```
function dwmode(){
    var body = document.querySelector('body')
    document.getElementById('dWmode').innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-sun"></i>';
        if(innerHTML == '<i class="fas fa-sun"></i>'){
            body.style.background = 'white'
    }
}
```

Comment: Any condition her is always true (or just `undefined` in the case of `innerHTML`). If you are looking for actual dark mode, maybe look into `@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){}` in CSS. Otherwise, this is confusing. You could even use the CSS to change the `content` of a `:before` to 'sun' or 'moon'.

Answer (score 0):

```js
body = document.querySelector("body");
sun = document.getElementById("sun");
moon = document.getElementById("moon");

function dwmode() {
  if (sun.style.visibility == "visible") {
    body.style.backgroundColor = "white"
    sun.style.visibility = "hidden";
    moon.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    body.style.backgroundColor = "gray"
    sun.style.visibility = "visible";
    moon.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }



}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.sunv {
  visibility: visible;
}

.moonv {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<i class="fas fa-sun sunv" id="sun" onclick="dwmode()"></i>
<i class="fas fa-moon moonv" id="moon" onclick="dwmode()"></i>
```